# what is the best way to securely send SMS?

Tags: sms

what is the best way to securely send details like bank account, credit card etc through SMS ?

is there any apps available for free ?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Answer (score 2):

[Signal by OpenWhisper Systems](https://whispersystems.org/) seems to be good, secure and free. Using it myself.

Edit: my bad, they don't do secure sms anymore.
Well, there's still [SMSSecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.smssecure.smssecure) app, which might be of use.

Comment: https://whispersystems.org/blog/goodbye-encrypted-sms/

Comment: @mattm Now that's some bad news. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily bad news. The main point is that secure messaging will not be over SMS, but over the IP network.